# How to get the data passed via AJAX and Jquery using $_POST?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i´m trying to pass simple html data to a php server using Ajax and Jquery. So i made a pretty simple script:

```
 <script>
      $("document").ready(function(){
        $(".enviarJson").on("click",function(){
            var valor = $(this).attr("value");
           // alert(valor);
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "HTML",
              url: "devolve.php",
              data: valor,
              success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);
              }
            });
            return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Here is the html:

```
    <form>
    <button class="enviarJson" value="q1?a1">Answer 1</button>
    <button class="enviarJson" value="q1?a2">Answer 2</button>
    </form>
```

Now my question is how do i get the data passed to **devolve.php** without knowing what is the id of the $_POST[]?

For example using a regular post form i could do something like this:

```
<form action="devolve.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then i could get the name on devolve.php by doing something like this:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Serialize the form data using jQuery's `.serialize()` function. Then the data will be available in the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given your POST data a name. it's going across as a bare value, which means there's nothing for PHP to use as a key in $_POST:

```
data: valor,
      ^---no name
```

Try

```
data: {name:valor},
```

which would let you use `$_POST['name']`.

Alternatively, you can read the raw POST data:

```
$name = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Thanks, as soon as i can i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) -

```
$(".enviarJson").on("click",function(){
        var valor = $('form').serialize(); // serializes all of the form data in name / value pairs
       // alert(valor);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "HTML",
          url: "devolve.php",
          data: valor,
          success: function(data) {
             alert(data);
          }
        });
        return false;
    })
```

It would be better if you gave your form some kind of identification in the event you have more than one form on the page.